# How to match figures with text

Tags: r, dataframe

I have no clue how to do this in R

I have an excel table with numbers from 0 to 9999. Each is characterised by a tex (eg. 110 -sleep).

Know I created a second excel table that consists SOME of the numbers from excel table 1.

I would like to create table 3 that match the name of the numbers from excel table 1 with excel table 2.

example

```
Table 1.csv

0     Other personal care
110   Sleep
111   Sleep in bed

Table 2.csv

0
111
```

Output

```
Table 3.csv

    0     Other personal care
    111   Sleep in bed
```

Comment: Do you need to do a merge/*join?

Comment: Also, maybe use [Excel's VLOOKUP function.](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 1):

merge the two dataframes

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3),text=c("Other personal care","Sleep","Sleep in bed"))
df2<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2))
new_dataset <- merge(df1,df2, by=c("ID"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table1 <- data.frame(num=1:6,
                 text=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))

table2 <- data.frame(num=c(1,2,4,6))

table3 <- table1[table1$num %in% table2$num, ]
```

Use `%in%` and possibly `which()` or `subset()`.